# How to know the size of a particular layer in Krita?

Tags: drawing, krita

I have a Krita file with a layer on it. I want to know the size of it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do so:

- right click on the name of your layer
- go to Properties
- check the dimensions in the properties pop up which just opened

[image: layer properties pop up with an arrow showing the dimensions section]

You can also:

- select your layer
- press F3 which is the shortcut for the Properties menu